# $cond dentro de un $sum

Tags: mongodb, nosql

quiero hacer una consulta compuesta en mongodb, la cual debe sumar 1 por cada true que detecte, pero no me esta funcionando de manera correcta, ya que me cuenta tanto los true como los false

```
{ 
_id: "resumen",
  Asistencia:{$sum:
    { $cond: [ asistencia: false, 1, 0 ] }
  }
}
```

esto dentro de un group, ¿Alguna idea de en que me equivoque?

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente era cuestión de agregar un $eq de la siguiente manera:

```
{ $cond: [ {$eq:["$asistencia", true]}, 1, 0 ] }
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera;

```
{ 
_id: "resumen",
  Asistencia:{$sum:
    { $cond: [ {$eq:["$asistencia", true]}, 1, 0 ] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en la forma en que declaras la condición.

Se desea realizar una etapa de agregación [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) en la cual se sumen la cantidad de documentos que cumplan cierta condición: valor del campo `asistencia` debe ser `true` (según lo planteado en la pregunta).

Se intenta una expresión de tipo [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) sin resultados:

```
$cond: [ asistencia: false, 1, 0 ]
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para solucionar el problema debemos entender la forma correcta en la que se utiliza el operador de expresión condicional en un proceso se [Agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) en MongoDB.

La expresión condicional acepta los siguientes dos tipos de sintaxis (tomado de la documentación oficial)

Sintaxis explícita (`if ... then ... else`):

```
{ $cond: { if: <boolean-expression>, then: <true-case>, else: <false-case> } }
```

Sintaxis compacta o de Array (`[cond, true, false]`):

```
{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }
```

Tal como tienes escrita tu expresión condicional tienes 2 errores muy evidentes, el primero es la condición como tal. En tu pregunta dices que quieres contar las veces que `asistencia` es `true`:

> *la cual debe sumar 1 por cada true que detecte*

Sin embargo, tienes lo siguiente:

```
asistencia: false
```

El segundo error, es que la sintaxis usada no es válida:

```
[ asistencia: false, 1, 0 ]
```

Claramente el primer elemento del Array: `asistencia: false` no es una expresión válida de Javascript, mucho menos de MongoDB.

Alguien podría sugerir pasar dicho elemento como un objeto:

```
$cond: [ {asistencia: false}, 1, 0 ]
```

Pero esto no diferencia los casos según `asistencia` sea `true` o `false`, sino que cuenta todos los documentos, debido a que el primer elemento es [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy). No se evalúa realmente el valor del campo asistencia pasado en el objeto, sino que se evalúa lo que devuelve dicha *expresión*.

Y es que debemos tener siempre en cuenta que las expresiones que deseamos evaluar sean expresiones válidas y que devuelvan un valor verdadero o falso. En este caso particular, un objeto (sin importar su contenido) siempre devolverá `true`, incluso si el mismo es un objeto vacío:

```
$cond: [ {}, 1, 0 ]
```

Al ser un objeto (vacío o no) el mismo devuelve `true` (es un valor `truthy`), por lo tanto suma 1 en cada documento, independientemente de si el mismo tiene su campo `asistencia` en `true` o en `false` o incluso si no tiene un campo `asistencia`, tal como se puede apreciar en el siguiente [MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lOvHa0-lAon), donde existen 8 documentos, 7 contienen el campo `asistencia`. Sin embargo, se cuentan los 8 documentos.

**La expresión**

La expresión que estás buscando debe evaluar efectivamente el valor del campo `asistencia`. En MongoDB, para comparar valores existe el operador [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html) para los procesos de agregación, el cual recibe los valores a comparar en un Array:

```
{ $eq: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }
```

Para indicarle a MongoDB el campo cuyo valor vamos a comparar, debemos escribirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
"$asistencia"
```

Nótese que va entre comillas y se le antepone un símbolo `$` delante del nombre del campo.

La expresión `$eq` se escribe entonces:

```
{ $eq: [ "$asistencia", true ] }
```

Toda tu expresión condicional entonces debe escribirse de la siguiente forma:

```
$cond: [ { $eq: ["$asistencia", true] }, 1, 0 ]
```

Aquí la expresión `$eq` devolverá `true` sólo cuando el campo `asistencia` tenga como valor `true`.

Puedes ver el siguiente [MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ar5I8QwQZj5) donde efectivamente se devuelve la cantidad de documentos que tienen su campo `asistencia` con valor de `true`.

Si se desea usar la sintaxis completa, sería así:

```
$cond: { if: { $eq: ["$asistencia", true] }, then: 1, else: 0 }
```

Nuevamente, dejo un [MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/38nA4WjTV2z) donde se ve esta implementación.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.