# ¿Cómo agrupar elementos usando Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Necesito crear una consulta usando mongoose, que me permita usar el grupo, para contar los elementos que están en estado INICIADO o NOINICIADO, para luego regresar el conteo de los elementos que se encuentran en cada uno de los estados.

Este es el json object con el que estoy trabajando.

```
[
{
estado: "INICIADO",
_id: "6057e0013a3dec1d44a7d152",
grupo: "lacteos",
ubicacion: "001",
total_items: 30,
__v: 0
},
{
estado: "INICIADO",
_id: "6057e0013a3dec1d44a7d153",
grupo: "lacteos",
ubicacion: "002",
total_items: 45,
__v: 0
},
{
estado: "INICIADO",
_id: "6057e0013a3dec1d44a7d154",
grupo: "lacteos",
ubicacion: "003",
total_items: 12,
__v: 0
},
{
estado: "NOINICIADO",
_id: "6057e0013a3dec1d44a7d155",
grupo: "lacteos",
ubicacion: "004",
total_items: 50,
__v: 0
},
{
estado: "NOINICIADO",
_id: "6057e0013a3dec1d44a7d156",
grupo: "medicamentos",
ubicacion: "005",
total_items: 23,
__v: 0
},
{
estado: "NOINICIADO",
_id: "6057e0013a3dec1d44a7d157",
grupo: "medicamentos",
ubicacion: "006",
total_items: 76,
__v: 0
}]
```

Por ejemplo, del grupo lacteos necesito regresar regresar un json con la siguiente estructura.

```
{
  'id' : null,
  'grupo': 'lacteos',
  'INICIADO' : 3,
  'NOINICIADO' : 1
}
```

Porque del grupo lacteos 3 de los elementos están con estado INICIADO y uno de los elementos está con estado NOINICIADO. Otro ejemplo sería con el grupo de medicamentos que debería regresarme el siguiente json.

```
{
  'id' : null,
  'grupo': 'medicamentos',
  'INICIADO' : 0,
  'NOINICIADO' : 2
}
```

Para poder hacer esto estoy tratando de hacer funcionar el siguiente código.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  
{
    "$group": {
      _id: {
        source: "$grupo",
        status: "$estado"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Pero no tengo muy claro como usar el grupo para generar la respuesta como la necesito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Lo que estás tratando de hacer es una suma condicional agrupando por un campo. Para ello te puedes apoyar en un proceso de agregación que cuente los elementos de acuerdo al valor de su campo `estado`. Una suma condicional de este tipo la explico en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409365/cond-dentro-de-un-sum/409762#409762), sin embargo tal vez no sea muy fácil de ver cómo aplicarla en tu caso, ya que estás intentando obtener 2 valores diferentes.

El resultado del proceso de agregación propuesto en mi respuesta sería parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "INICIADO": 11,
    "NOINICIADO": 6,
    "_id": "medicamentos"
  },
  {
    "INICIADO": 4,
    "NOINICIADO": 10,
    "_id": "carnes"
  },
  {
    "INICIADO": 11,
    "NOINICIADO": 8,
    "_id": "lacteos"
  }
]
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La siguiente es una posible solución, usando un proceso de [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) sobre la colección de MongoDB.

Para obtener el resultado mostrado anteriormente vamos a utilizar 1 etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) en la cual usaremos el operador [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) para contar los elementos de acuerdo a una condición.

La idea es contar tanto los elementos que tienen un valor `INICIADO` como un valor `NOINICIADO` en su campo `estado`.

La suma ha de ser condicionada, ya que para el campo `estado` tenemos 2 posibles valores. Para sumar (contar) condicionalmente se hace uso de una expresión condicional: [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond), como la siguiente:

```js
{
  $cond: {
    if: {
      <condicion>,
    },
    then: <valor si se cumple condicion>,
    else: <valor si no se cumple>
  }
}
```

El valor de `<condicion>` debe ser una expresión que devuelva `true` o `false`. En el caso de tu pregunta se desea saber si el campo `estado` es igual a la cadena `INICIADO`, por lo tanto podemos escribir la siguiente expresión condicional:

```js
{
  $cond: {
    if: {
      $eq: ["$estado", "INICIADO"]
    },
    then: 1,
    else: 0
  }
}
```

La expresión condicional anterior devuelve 1 si el valor del campo `estado` es igual ([`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html)) al valor `INICIADO` y devuelve 0 en caso contrario.

Ahora que tenemos una forma de devolver una expresión numérica, podemos usarla dentro del operador `$sum` que recibe siempre un valor numérico y suma los documentos que sean agrupados.

Al ser una suma condicinada, te dará el total de los elementos que tengan su estado en `INICIADO` y podemos escribir otra suma condicionada para contar los que tengan su estado en `NOINICIADO`:

```js
{
  //...
  INICIADO: {
    $sum: {
      $cond: {
        $if: {
          $eq: ["$estado", "INICIADO"]
        },
        then: 1,
        else: 0
      }
    }
  },
  NOINICIADO: {
    $sum: {
      $cond: {
        $if: {
          $eq: ["$estado", "NOINICIADO"]
        },
        then: 1,
        else: 0
      }
    }
  },
  //...
}
```

En el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IvE6ZCdbL6q) puedes ver un ejemplo de este proceso de agregación. Se generan 50 documentos de forma aleatoria con los datos necesarios para reproducir tu colección y se aplica el siguiente proceso de agregación:

```js
db.datos.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$grupo",
      INICIADO: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$estado",
                "INICIADO"
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      NOINICIADO: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$estado",
                "NOINICIADO"
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.