# Cálculo de total en consulta de MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Buen día,

Estoy efectuando una consulta para totalizar la cantidad de votos según el criterio de agrupación existente en el campo "Participó" (que viene marcado en "S" si la persona votó y en "N" si se abstuvo de votar). La cantidad suma justamente la cantidad de personas que participaron y se abstuvieron. Para ello, hice esto:

```
    [{$group: {
  _id: '$Participo',
  Cantidad: {$sum: 1},
  }
}]
```

Ahora bien, así como tengo la consulta, me dice cuántos registros hay de forma separada de "S" y "N", pero necesito también que dentro de esa misma consulta se incluya un campo llamado "Total" que me sume la cantidad de registros de "S" + "N", para que esto me sirva más adelante para calcular los porcentajes. He intentado, pero no se cómo hacerlo porque soy novato en esto.

Agradecería la orientación que pudieran darme.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [$cond dentro de un $sum](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409365/cond-dentro-de-un-sum)

Comment: Lo que buscas hacer se llama suma condicional, es pregunta ya fue realizada en el sitio. Saludos